# Prove carpet has positive Hausdorff measure in its dimension

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

> Given $D\subset\{0,1,2,\dots n-1\}\times\{0,\dots,m-1\}$, let $$K(D)=\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_kn^{-k},b_km^{-k}):(a_k,b_k)\in D\forall k\}.$$
>   Show that if $D$ has uniform horizontal fibers (i.e. the number of rectangles in each row of $K(D)$ is equal), it means that $K(D)$ has positive Hausdorff measure in its dimension.

I find the formulation of this question a bit unclear I know that suppose $K(D)$ has uniform fibers the Malinowski and Hausdorff dimensions agree and $$\dim K(D)=1+\log_n\frac{\#D}{m}$$(where #D is the cardinality of D) but I cannot understand how it implies that exist a positive Hausdorff measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lemma is theorem 5.8 of Falconer's *The Geometry of Fractal Sets* and, I believe, is directly applicable to your situation.

---

Let $F$ be a subset of the $xz$ plane, let $A$ be any subset of 
the $z$-axis, and for $z\in A$, let
$$F_z = \{x: (x,z)\in F\}.$$
Suppose there is a constant $c>0$ such that ${\cal H}^{t}(F_z) > c$ for all $z\in A$. Then 
$${\cal H}^{s+t}(F) \geq b \; c \; {\cal H}^s(A),$$
where $b$ depends only on $s$ and $t$.

---

Examining your specific question in a bit more detail, the notation is, indeed, a bit difficult.  It was introduced in [a paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/carpets/carpets.pdf) by [Curt McMullen](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/), though, so who am I to complain?  Let's examine a couple of simple examples to help us figure it out.

First, let's look a simpler, one-dimensional example.  Suppose that $n=3$ and $D=\{0,2\}$  The one-dimensional analogue of your sum set is then 
$$\left\{x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k}: a_k = 0 \text{ or } 2\right\}.$$
This is a well known characterization of the Cantor set.

The Cantor set, of course, is often described as a self-similar set, in that it is made of two copies of itself scaled by the factor $1/3$.  Your set $K(D)$ is self-similar only when $m=n$ but, more generally, is self-affine; it is made of smaller copies of itself scaled by the factor $1/n$ horizontally and $1/m$ vertically.  To make this clear, let is again look at an example.  Let's suppose that $n=6$, $m=3$, and that
$$D=\{\{0, 0\}, \{1, 0\}, \{3, 0\}, \{5, 0\}, \{1, 1\}, \{2, 1\}, \{4, 1\}, \{5, 1\}, \{0, 2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{4, 2\}, \{5, 2\}\}.$$
Then,
$$K(D)=\left\{(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_kn^{-k},b_km^{-k}): (a_k,b_k)\in D\right\}$$
can be visualized like so:

[image]

The rectangle labeled $(i,j)$ is the set of all points in $K(D)$ such that $(a_1,b_1)=(i,j)$.  We can iterate the procedure to obtain a better visualization of $K(D)$.  After several iterates, we get something like so:

[image]

Note that we have the same number of rectangles in each row. That's the manifestation of the "uniform horizontal fibers" which allows us to apply the lemma.

Comment: what do you mean by $F_z$?

Comment: @DanisFischer I mean the slice of $F$ at level $z$.  Sorry about that - I copied this from a paper of mine that defines $F_z$ prior to the statement.  I'll edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks. now which $t,s$ should I pick? and just to verify $\mathcal{H}^s(A)>0$ follows from the uniform fibers?

Comment: I'm thinking that $s=1$ and that $t$ is the common Hausdorff dimension of the cross-sections.  Assuming that the these cross-sections all have $t$-dimensional measure bounded below by some positive constant (which I think is the case), then you've got it.  Also, I'm assuming the upper bound is easier.

Comment: Thanks. (hopefully) Final question: why $\mathcal{H}^s(A)>0$?

Comment: @DanisFischer $A$ is an interval in this case - is it not?

Comment: So by this notation we take $F=K(D)$ and $A$ to be a subset of the second coordinate ? who tells us that every subset of z-axis is interval? can't we pick $A=\{p_1,p_2,\dots p_k\}$ a discrete set of points?

Comment: @DanisFischer I think you should try to draw your set.

Comment: I drew it. thanks again. I'm not sure how the theorem finishes the proof (sounds silly, I know) so just to verify: to have positive measure in the dimension means that $\exists q:\mathcal{H}^q(F)\ge 0$?

Comment: @DanisFischer No, it's not enough that there is just *some* $q$. Positive measure in the dimension means that ${\cal H}^q(F)>0$, where $q$ is specifically chosen to be the Hausdorff dimension of $F$. I've added some to my answer which I hope helps.

Comment: Now I (purport) to understand a bit better. Thanks once again. By the way: in which software do you use to visualize these IFS (e.g the last figure)?

Comment: @DanisFischer Good - glad this helped. I generated the images using my own Mathematica package.